GitLab project with Terraform
I'm creating a GitLab server and project using Terraform.
I'm having a problem with the provider's token.
I create a instance for the server, and with a script I define the token for GitLab.

"echo 'Creating GitLab access token script'",
      "echo \"user = User.find_by(username: 'root')\" > create_token.rb",
      "echo \"token = user.personal_access_tokens.create!(name: 'Automated Token', scopes: [:api, :read_user, :read_repository, :write_repository, :sudo], expires_at: 30.days.from_now)\" >> create_token.rb",
      "echo \"token.set_token('${var.gitlab_token}')\" >> create_token.rb",
      "echo \"token.save!\" >> create_token.rb",
      "echo \"File.open('/tmp/gitlab_token.txt', 'w') { |file| file.write(token.token) }\" >> create_token.rb",
      "sudo gitlab-rails runner -e production /home/ubuntu/create_token.rb"

After that I want to create a project using the GitLab provider:
provider "gitlab" {
  token = var.gitlab_token
  base_url = "https://<gitlab_server>/api/v4/"
}
resource "gitlab_project" "example" {...}


My problem is that when I define the gitlab_token manually it works (but security wise it isn't good), but when I try using some kind of random definition (I treid random_password provider or openssl rand) it doesn't work and I get:
Error: GET http://<ip>/api/v4/user: 401 {message: 401 Unauthorized}
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/gitlabhq/gitlab"],.

I tested the token I created randomly with curl and I get the right response.
I also treid making sure the random token is a string but that didn't help.


when I try using some kind of random definition (I tried
random_password provider or openssl rand) it doesn't work

According to the documentation of the gitlab provider, token is the OAuth2 Token, Project, Group, Personal Access Token or CI Job Token used to connect to GitLab.
In other words, you need to provide an existing token to connect to the provider:
provider "gitlab" {
  token = var.gitlab_token
}

As an alternative, use the GITLAB_TOKEN environment variable to authenticate to the provider instead of a variable like var.gitlab_token. This approach is better because it avoids storing sensitive information in the Terraform state file.
